# Confusion of integrating libs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, jruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am using  Netbeans IDE. While importing a new project, I used the inbuilt JRuby 1.4 that comes with Netbeans as the Ruby version. The main reason I want the JRuby is because of its debugging abilities.

Now the doubt/problem I have is integrating libraries/plugins. One of the assignments I have requires me to use a iCalendar library. The project I checkedout has a "vendor" folder where these libraries have to be checked-in (correct me If I am wrong). But I just installed the iCalendar using the Gem Manager of Jruby. Now, how would I have have permanently store this library in the vendor project?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack the gem in your vendor gems folder

```
cd vendor/gems

gem unpack icalendar
```

Now you have the icalendar gem in your gem folder

If you get any warnings about gem specification files after this when going to console or starting up application then just do `rake gems:refresh_specs`